# Oozie 4.3.0 build failed on Hadoop 2.9.0

Tags: hadoop2, oozie

I ran the build with commands like this:

```
./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests
```

and this:

```
./mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -D hadoop.version=2.3.0 -P uber -P hadoop-2
```

But all failed with error messages:

`[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /root/oozie-4.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-utils-2/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:[31,49] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  package org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.protocolrecords
/root/oozie-4.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-utils-2/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:[70,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  class LauncherMainHadoopUtils
/root/oozie-4.3.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-utils-2/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/action/hadoop/LauncherMainHadoopUtils.java:[71,11] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 3 errors 
...`

I also tried to export `HADOOP_CLASSPATH` and `CLASSPATH` variables to point to the Hadoop libraries but all failed with same error. I am not sure if it is failed because the build command can't find hadoop libraries or it does not support Hadoop version 2.9.0.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watch it my newly created blog to install `oozie-4.3.0` on combination of `hadoop-2.9.0` step by step,

[Installing apache oozie-4.3.0 on existing apache hadoop-2.9.0](https://oozie-4-3-0.blogspot.in/2017/12/installing-oozie-430-with-existing.html)

hope this will help you.

Comment: the difference between the environment you set up Oozie from mine is you built oozie on top of hadoop and I build it on a Hadoop `edge node`. I will try to see if I can have luck by following your blog instructions. Anyway, good to know Oozie can be built with Hadoop v2.9.0.

Comment: @robert first I wrote my blog, and then I searched the question where people failed to install oozie, and I feel that there will many guys who would get a help from my blog, later I searched your question, and the time I replied there are no such helping replies for the question, and as per my blog you can see, there are many plots left till running the first time oozie web console and are many more steps, making oozie distro is only the first step, there are much more pain left after it.

Comment: The mentioned blog post did solve the issue. By comparing the difference between the blog and my own environment, I think it is the variables added to `.bashrc` help oozie build script locate the Hadoop libraries. From this point, I only can say the Oozie documentation is very ambiguous. One other thing, I think a typo in the blog post at place of oozie db initiation. It should be `ooziedb.sh`, but it is `oozied.sh`.

Comment: thanks but still there are much more things and conditions I know people get failed after installing oozie and mesh with the workflow, coordinators and properties files, you can't keep the people happy for all things.